# How to remove the table row to the end of other rows

Tags: javascript, mysql

i am trying to fetch multiple data to the table , but there is one row which is dubplicating is totalColumn , when i remove duplicate , the rest resides in front of the table. what i want i to move that front of row to the end of the table

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    ...                
    <tr class="totalColumn">
      <td>Total</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="sumofamount">@FuelHistory.sumOfTwo(d.driver.Id) Litres</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript used to remove a row :

```
$('.totalColumn').each(function() {
    var thisId = $(this).find('.sumofamount').text();
    var $rowsToGroup = $(this).nextAll('tr').filter(function() {
      return $(this).find('.sumofamount').text() === thisId;
    });

    $rowsToGroup.each(function() {
      $(this).remove();
    }
);
```

Comment: How does a table row move t the left?? Or do you mean if the row had a duplicate, you want them at the end of the table with the duplicates removed?

Comment: you question is not clear ...  what mean  with left rows .. show a proper data sample and the expected result

Comment: I mean the rest row i need it to go to the end of the table.

Comment: Just do `table.appendChild(row)`. If the row is already in the table it will be moved to the end. If you only have a reference to the row, then `row.parentNode.appendChild(row)`. The code looks really turgid, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @RobG i am trying to fetch multiple data to the table , but there is one row which is dubplicating is `totalColumn` , when i remove duplicate , the rest resides in front of the table. what i want i to move that front of row to the end of the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have duplicated rows and only want to keep only one, and move that one to the end of the table. The following removes all but one of the *totalColumn* rows, then moves the remaining one to the end of the containing table section:

```js
function fixTable(){
  // Get the total column rows
  var totalRows = document.querySelectorAll('.totalColumn');
  // Remove all but the first one
  for (var i=1, iLen=totalRows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    totalRows[i].parentNode.removeChild(totalRows[i]);
  }
  //  Move first to end of containing table section
  totalRows[0].parentNode.appendChild(totalRows[0]);     
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>foo<td>
    <tr><td>bar<td>
    <tr class="totalColumn"><td>Total</td><td>1,000</td></tr>
    <tr><td><td>
    <tr class="totalColumn"><td>Total</td><td>1,000</td></tr>
    <tr><td>fee<td>
    <tr><td>fumm<td>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="fixTable()">Fix table</button>
```

You could also use *forEach* to do the same thing, but the above is compatible with all browsers back to IE 8 without polyfills or transpiling.

The *fixTable* function could be written:

```
function fixTable(){
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.totalColumn'),
    (row, i) => row.parentNode[(i? 'remove' : 'append') + 'Child'](row)
  );
}
```

But I think the *for* loop is easier to read and very much more compatible with older browsers (and is probably faster to boot).